# How to invokePrivate on a function with implicit parameters

Tags: scala

How do I invoke XYZ.doSomething method for these classes:

XYZ.scala

```
object XYZ {

  private def doSomething(i : Int)(implicit s: String): String {
    s + i.toString
  }
}
```

XYZTest.scala

```
class XYZTest extends FunSpec with PrivateMethodTester {
  describe("SomeTest") {
    it("Can't find a private method named: doSomething :( ") {
      implicit lazy val someStr: String = "sahil"
      val doSomething = PrivateMethod[String]('doSomething)
      val myStr = XYZ invokePrivate doSomething(1)
      assert(myStr == "sahil1")
    }
  }
  describe("SomeTest") {
    it("This doesn't even compile :( ") {
      val doSomething = PrivateMethod[String]('doSomething)
      val myStr = XYZ invokePrivate doSomething(1)("sahil")
      assert(myStr == "sahil1")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct answer is:

```
object XYZ {

  private def doSomething(i : Int)(implicit s: String): String = {
    s + i.toString
  }
}

class XYZTest extends FunSpec with PrivateMethodTester {
  describe("SomeTest") {
    it("Can't find a private method named: doSomething :( ") {
      implicit lazy val someStr: String = "sahil"
      val doSomething = PrivateMethod[String]('doSomething)
      val myStr = XYZ invokePrivate doSomething(1, someStr)
      assert(myStr == "sahil1")
    }
  }
}
```

Brief view on `invokePrivate` method shows that it does not support `implicits`, but looks like it treats `currying` argument list as general sequence of arguments

`def invokePrivate[T](invocation : PrivateMethodTester.this.Invocation[T])`

where `args` is the sequence:

`final class Invocation[T](val methodName : scala.Symbol, val args : scala.Any*)`